# Write snapshot back to base qcow2 file

Tags: qemu

I create a snapshot of my qcow2 image file like

```
qemu-img -c before_update Server_sda_qcow2.img
```

After I have updated the system and everything is working well. I will
write the snapshot back to the base file and delete the snapshot.

I tried

```
qemu-img -a before_update Server_sda_qcow2.img
```

But it seems that it won't work.

How can I archieve this with qemu-img?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem by myself:

In my case I only need to delete the snapshot with:

```
qemu-img -d before_update Server_sda_qcow2.img
```

When I will bring the base file back to the snapshot I have to do:

```
qemu-img -a before_update Server_sda_qcow2.img
```